Bash script to close user session after a remote work
I have terminal linux server (xrdp) and I need a script that will terminate the session and send the user to the login screen after completing the rdp connection
OS: CentOS 8
I wrote this, but i sense i need something more
#!/bin/bash
if
xfreerdp /v:"my-IP" /u:"my-user" /p:"pass" -f
else
gnome-session-quit
fi

The idea is this: The user starts his computer, logs into his account, the script runs automatically and connects it to the rdp session on the server. After the user finishes working, he completes the connection and the script sends it to the login screen. In fact, the user has little interaction with the installed OS on the computer

Try with:
#!/bin/bash

xfreerdp /v:"my-IP" /u:"my-user" /p:"pass" -f
wait
gnome-session-quit

Explanation: the wait bash command waits for each just spawned processes to terminate, then goes on with the execution of the next instructions.

Perhaps the answer should explain in more detail why the OP's attempt was wrong, though?

@triplee I added the explanation.

Hmm, but the OP's problem was that they (weirdly!) used an if statement. I'm not asking why this works, I'm asking why theirs didn't.

Regardless of the wrong if syntax, it would not work to close session after the xdrp session, so I provided a complete solution to the posted use case.
